# How to make a ES6 class visible for both the server and client scripts in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

So, I have 2 classes for shapes in a script that's called `shapes.js`

```
class Shape {

    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
    } 

}
class Cube extends Shape {
    constructor(x, y, t) {
        super(x, y);
        this.t = t;
    }
}
```

How do I import both of these in my `server.js` or other js files? I know `Shape` is nothing more than an abstract class right now, but I want to test the functionality of importing multiple classes. I have tried doing it in the following ways:

```
var shape = require('/shapes');
var Shape = shape.Shape, Cube = shape.Cube;

or

import {Shape, Cube} from 'shapes'
import {Shape, Cube} from '/shapes'
```

I have also tried exporting them in `shapes.js` at the end of the file like this :

```
module.exports = {Shape, Cube}

or

export {Shape, Cube}
```

I've tried all the possibilities I've been provided within the basic tutorials, the result is either an error or a blank white screen with no errors. I have been really stuck on this one, would appreciate some help, thank you

Comment: If you put `module.exports = {Shape, Cube}` in the `shapes.js` file and then do `const {Shape, Cube} = require('./shapes');` in other file, then I'm pretty sure there is no way it won't work. Or there is something else messed up

Comment: Since you tagged this question with `node.js` – are you talking about using these classes on the server side with Node.js, or are you talking about using them on the client side (in the browser)?

Comment: ^ both actually

Comment: I'm asking because it is very different on the server with Node.js. There, JavaScript modules are not supported yet, so you'd have to use `module.exports` and `require`there. In the browser, most support JavaScript modules now, so you'd go with `export` and `import`, as described here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to use the ES Module syntax :

`import {Shape, Cube} from 'shapes'` to [import a module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

`export {Shape, Cube}` to [export a module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Most browsers support this.Unfortunately! Node.js suppport ES6 but doesn't support ESModule syntax (or [only experimental way](https://nodejs.org/docs/v11.10.0/api/esm.html))
So you need to transpile your code with [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) and [this plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs)

Here the .babelrc file to configure babel:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

If you use [babel-register](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register) the transformation occurs when the file is required(imported)

Answer (score 1):

The `module.exports` syntax is the best way to export your code. However, the best way to import them differs between Node and browsers.

```
module.exports = {Shape, Cube}; // in file with classes defined

// below are different ways to import
const { Shape, Cube } = require('./shapes'); // Node
import { Shape, Cube } from './shapes'; // modern browsers
```

The Node line has something called a destructuring statement. It just prevents you from having to define both `shape` and `Shape`/`Cube`.

You said in your question that you tried both `module.exports` and a require statement. My guess is that you either a) didn't try both at the same time or b) without the `./` in your require statement, the program couldn't find your file.

Note that the export/import keyword do not work in Node - they work only in modern browsers. As other answers have noted, there are ways to make those work. However, I would generally recommend against them for smaller scale projects, particularly if you're just getting familiar with this stuff.

Comment: Right now what I have is `module.exports = {Shape, Cube}; // shapes.js`, `const {Shape, Cube} = require('./shapes'); // server.js` and `import { Shape, Cube } from './shapes'; // game.js ` When I run the node server with `node --experimental-modules server.js` everything is alright but when I open `http://localhost:3000` there is a blank white screen and no errors. In `index.html` I specified the type -> `<script src="game.js" type="module"></script>` Do I need babeljs to fix this?

Comment: `module.exports` syntax is not the best way to export your code. It's used only to export CommonJS module. The standard is now to use ES module with `export` syntax

Comment: You shouldn't have to use --experimental-modules to make your server use a `module.exports`. If it's still not working, you have some other error. I suggest trying to figure it out using console.logs to figure out if it's being exported and imported.

Comment: @BenCooper it's as if the `game.js` script doesn't get recognized at all. When I run the server, what appears is just a white screen when I go to `http://localhost:${port}`.

Comment: Even stuff that got nothing to do with the classes I import won't work such as setting the background color, etc

Comment: Everything had been working properly until I decided to create my classes in a seperate file and then import/export them. Worst of all, there is no error that shows up so I can't really figure out what could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my last projects I used Typescript with node.js it's very powerful so I use `namespace` way :

shapes.ts :

```
   export namespace Shapes {

    export class A {

    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
      } 

    }
   export class B {

    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y
      } 

    }
  }
```

usage :

```
import Shapes from 'shapes'

let shapeA = new Shapes.A();
```